# Cannot understand authorization failures in ActiveMQ REST API with client ID

Tags: rest, activemq-classic

We were using the ActiveMQ 5.13.2 REST API with oneShot to consume messages from a queue.

However, we have some strange problems with the consumers so we are trying to transition to using a client ID and I am seeing errors I simply cannot find an explanation to.

When I try

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 23962c3f-79fe-c0b7-ea96-13be5c8f2c09" "http://localhost:8161/api/message/anomalies?type=queue&clientId\=koo"
```

(notice the backslash before the client ID)

I get messages from the queue.
When I try

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: d2b6291c-1bf0-5b0a-cf9b-4d0998867004" "http://localhost:8161/api/message/anomalies?type=queue&clientId=koo"
```

(no backslash this time)

```
I get HTTP error 500 with messages for the exception such as:
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not post JMS message: org.apache.activemq.ConnectionFailedException: The JMS connection has failed: Force close due to SecurityException on connect

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [system] or password is invalid.
```

I actually authenticated the call with the user: admin

I set the ActiveMQ log level to ALL, but I can't find anything informative. I see the same exceptions in the wrapper.log and I see in the activemq.log the correct queue name.

I don't want to use the URL that works before I understand why it works and why the other URL doesn't.

Comment: From the description, I'm not quite sure if your error has the same *cause* as mine (though the error message is exactly the same), but please take a look at [this other post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/169770/99140); it may or may not help you.

Comment: Thank you @Haroldo_OK we gave up on using the REST api and started using JMS instead, it is much more stable and understandable

Comment: Okay, you're welcome.